# Neo4j cypher query takes a lot of time

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with this query

MATCH (I1:Interface), (I2:Interface)                        WHERE I1.IfIPAddress = '172.16.42.9' AND                        I2.IfIPAddress = '172.16.42.10'                        WITH Count(I1) + Count(I2) AS iCount, I1, I2 
WHERE iCount = 2
return iCount;

where there are 5000 interface nodes.
Why does it take a lot of time for the query to execute and still it does not executes?

Comment: Just to understand: you're looking for those two interfaces, with specific IPs, and you want to return a result only if any interface has either 1 or 2 occurrencies (in case of one both, otherwise just the one with 2). Is it right?

Comment: Yes. I want both the interfaces to exists before creating a link and that's what the first part of the query is doing. If both exists and no repetitions I count will return 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to test if both Interface instances exist, you can just do this:

```
MATCH (i1:Interface {IfIPAddress:'172.16.42.9'}), (i2:Interface {IfIPAddress:'172.16.42.10'})
RETURN i1, i2;
```

If both exist, then a single row (with the i1 and i2 nodes) will be returned, otherwise 0 rows will be returned.

Also, to speed up these queries, you should either create an index, or a uniqueness constraint (if no two Interface nodes can have the same IfIPAddress value).

To create the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Interface(IfIPAddress);
```

To create the uniqueness constraint instead (which also automatically creates the above index for you):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (i:Interface)
   ASSERT i.IfIPAddress IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the difference between the two match statements and how does neo4j treat these 2 matches

Comment: Your original query does the same matching, and in addition counts the number of matches. Counting is not necesaary.

Comment: @Nipun Did I answer your question?

Comment: the real problem was it was taking a lot of time in executing this query and after waiting for around 10 min the query didnt finished. I am still puzzled as it should not take so much of time. BTW, I have not indexed but still it should not take that much of time

Comment: Yes, I would not expect it to take > 10 minutes to iterate twice through 5000 nodes. Can you try indexing, and see if it still never gets a result?